How to make a function accept all type of iterators, but specialising only one type?
As per How to make constructor accept all type of iterators? I am trying to have a function accept iterators from different container types. Unlike that question, i want those containers to have only the specific type of elements. However, if i use the following code, i lose the ability to control the element type:
template<std::input_iterator ITER>
void f(ITER start, ITER end)
{
    for(auto it=start; it!=end; ++it)
    {
        static_assert(std::is_arithmetic<decltype(*it)>::value, "Not arithmetic");
    }
}

In here static_assert is not a very poor solution, because the error that i get is anything, but trivial to understand.
Let's imagine my main as
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v_good{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}};
    std::vector<std::string> v_bad{{std::string("hello"), std::string("world")}};
    std::list<int> l_good{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}};
    
    f(v_good.begin(), v_good.end());
    f(l_good.begin(), l_good.end());
    f(v_bad.begin(), v_bad.end()); // at this point i want to get a compilation error
    
    return 0;
}


std::is_arithmetic<decltype(*it)>::value is almost surely not what you want. Typically decltype(*it) will be a reference type, which can't be arithmetic. Also, *it may not even be a reference to the value type. It may be e.g. a proxy type that only converts to the value type. You need to figure out whether you want to check std::iter_value_t or std::iter_reference_t.

"because the error that i get is anything, but trivial to understand." - did you try changing the error message, from "Not arithmetic" to "The iterators you pass to the function f must contain arithmetic elements"?  You have nearly full control over the error message.

You can constrain the value_type of the iterator (std::iter_value_t) to be an arithmetic type by
template<std::input_iterator ITER>
  requires std::is_arithmetic_v<std::iter_value_t<ITER>>
void f(ITER start, ITER end)
{
    for (auto it=start; it!=end; ++it)
    {
       // ...
    }
}

In C++20, the type returned by a range's end() (i.e., the sentinel type) can be different from its begin(), so you may also need
template<std::input_iterator ITER, std::sentinel_for<ITER> SENT>
  requires std::is_arithmetic_v<std::iter_value_t<ITER>>
void f(ITER start, SENT end)
{
    for(auto it=start; it!=end; ++it)
    {
       // ... 
    }
}


The main advantage here is overloading in my opinion; this f can be overloaded with ones that can handle non-arithmetic iterated ranges.

You could move the is_arithmetic requirement out into a concept of its own, below called iterator_over_arithmetic_type:
template <class ITER>
concept iterator_over_arithmetic_type =
    std::input_iterator<ITER> &&
    std::is_arithmetic_v<std::iter_value_t<ITER>>;

template <iterator_over_arithmetic_type ITER>
void f(ITER start, ITER end) {
    for (auto it = start; it != end; ++it) {
    }
}

